# Preloading image w/ JS still results in image flash

Tags: html, css, preload

Take a look at the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LdukG/6/

There is a div that is given a different background on hover. The image is somewhat large in size in this case in order to illustrate my point.

I have basic image preload setup in JavaScript to preload this hover image. Open up Chrome Dev Tools and look at the Network tab. If you clear SHIFT+Reload the page, you will see that the preload background hover image does get preloaded.

**But there is still an Image Flash**

However, if you hover over the image and watch carefully, you will see that the image has that brief flash of white before showing the hover image. This is the same kind of image flash that you see if you don't preload images. Also if you watch the Network Tab, you will see that when you first hover over the div, it loads the background hover image AGAIN. So now it's in there twice.

It makes me think that the image preload simply isn't working. But if this is the case, then why does the preload image show up under the Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab?

Here is the JS preload script:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/zmkstudio/zmkstudio1103/zmkstudio110300066/8993167-abstract-water-color-painting-random-red-texture-background.jpg";
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: It seems that the fanpop image does not load in the jsFiddle. Can you demo this with an image which will show up?

Comment: Appears to show up fine for me. It doesn't show up for you?

Comment: Nope. I can navigate to the url but I do not see the image load in jsFiddle.net. Some sites do block jsFiddle.net.

Comment: Okay I updated it with a new image. Can't imagine why jsFiddle would be block when you view it but not me.

Comment: Okay, I can see the new image now. However, I do not see a white flash. Are you still seeing it?

Comment: I used a placeholder image as I had the same problem.  I see no flash.  http://jsfiddle.net/LdukG/7/